# "with" construct from JavaScript in Scala

Tags: javascript, scala

Does Scala have something similar to JavaScript's `with`, or can it be somehow achieved (e.g. library, implicits or macro)?

Example of `with` in JS:

```js
function p(){ 
    document.write("I am " + this.constructor.name + ".<br>");
}

function o1(){
    this.p = p;
}


var i1 = new o1();
i1.p();

p();

with(i1){ p(); }
```

Output:

```
I am o1.
I am Window.
I am o1.
```

Example of what I'm looking for:

```scala
class A { def x { ... } }
val a = new A
with(a){ x }
```

---

Only thing that occurred to me was using anonymous functions, but it's just a name substitution, nothing more (and also it's quite verbose).

```scala
( (aa:A) => aa.x )(a)
```

Comment: You should *never* use `with` in JS. It's broken.

Comment: it's not quite clear why would you want `with(a){ x }`. Can you elaborate on this? (I'm asking because similar construction is definitely possible, but does not make sense to me)

Comment: I would like `with`-like construct because IMO it's looks clearer/better (doesn't occupy so much space, more concise) than `val`s with limited scope: `{/*newLine*/val a = someRealyLongExpression /*newLine*/a.method1 /*newLine*/a.method2/*newLine*/ }` vs. `with(someRealyLongExpression){/*newLine*/method1/*newLine*/method2/*newLine*/}` (`import` looks not that bad, but it doesn't work with `var`s).

Comment: @Unrealsolver Not really to the topic. I'm not using JS, not planning to, not asking about and it doesn't matter if some implementations of JS can't handle `with` well. This is a Scala question. JS's `with` is only an example (and in original question is also example of what I'd like to achieve in Scala).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import a._
// code below can now use a's methods without referencing it
```

If you want to limit scope of the import, use braces:

```
{
  import a._
  // namespace madness
}
// everything's back to normal here
```

Example from REPL:

```
scala> val i = ""
i: java.lang.String = ""

scala> import i._
import i._

scala> length
res0: Int = 0
```

---

You can also perform a limited import:

```
import a.{thingImGonnaUse, anotherImportantThing}
```

or even rename them:

```
import a.{thingImGonnaUse => tigu, anotherImportantThing => ait}
```

This is more powerful than just doing `val ait = a.anotherImportantThing _` because it still allows you to use overloaded versions:

```
scala> val i = "0123456"
i: java.lang.String = 0123456

scala> import i.{substring => x}
import i.{substring=>x}

scala> x(3)
res1: java.lang.String = 3456

scala> x(2,3)
res2: java.lang.String = 2

scala> val y = i.substring _
<console>:15: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method substring in class String of type (x$1: Int, x$2: Int)java.lang.String
and  method substring in class String of type (x$1: Int)java.lang.String
match expected type ?
       val y = i.substring _
                 ^
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I had no idea that import statement can reference instances.

Comment: Not sure if I should leave question as answered, because `import` cannot be used on `var`s (`which` from JS works on "everything", at least I think).

Comment: `var x = ...; val y = x; import y._`

Comment: Well, it works, but seems rather verbose. Solution I'm looking for should have improved readability of code, with this approach I'm not sure if it would look really better/clearer.